# Fill a range (multiple columns) down multiple rows - google-apps-script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I had success filling a single column (A) with the value found in range A1...

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastRow = ss.getDataRange().getNumRows();  
  var rngVal = ss.getRange("A1").getValue()
  ss.getRange("A2:A"+lastRow).setValue(rngVal)
```

So then I thought I was on easy-street, and I tried to modify/apply that to a larger range by filling a multi-column range with the values found in range C1:H1...

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastRow = ss.getDataRange().getNumRows();  
  var rngVal = ss.getRange("C1:H1").getValues()
  ss.getRange("C2:H"+lastRow).setValues(rngVal)
```

Apparently there is a bit more to this than simply slapping an "S" onto the end of the word "Value".

The error reads as follows:

> Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 10

(FYI: var lastRow = 11)

Btw, I get no error if I use Value instead of Value***s***, although I end up with cells full of the value found only in range C1.

So I'm close.... or way off. One of those.

Help???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is quite explicit... the size of the array must fit into the range in both getValues and setValues. Try it like this
:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow()  
  var rngVal = ss.getRange("C1:H"+lastRow).getValues();// get an array of 10 "rows" and 6 "columns"
  ss.getRange("C2:H"+(lastRow+1)).setValues(rngVal);//write back this array to a range that has the same size. (starting from Row2 it must ends on lastRow+1 to keep the same number of "rows"
}
```

This function will shift the range C1:H last Row to C2:H lastRow+1, not sure it is very useful but that's not the point here ;-)

---

EDIT : sorry, I didn't understand exactly your requirement... here is a code that reproduce data from C1:H1 in all rows below

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow()  
  var rngVal = ss.getRange("C1:H1").getValues();// get an array of the first row
  var rowData = rngVal[0]
  var newData = []
  for(n=1;n<lastRow;++n){newData.push(rowData)}
  ss.getRange("C2:H"+lastRow).setValues(newData);//write back this array to a range that has the same size. (starting from Row2 it must ends on lastRow+1 to keep the same number of "rows"
}
```

**EDIT2 following your comment below :**

*A word of explanation :*

When using `range.getValues()` we get a 2 dimensions array, meaning an array of arrays that can be represented as follow : `[[data1,data2,data3],[data4,data5,data6]]` data1, 2 & 3 are the value of the first array (index 0) and data 4,5 & 6 are the values of the second array (index 1).  So if you want to get the values in the first array you have to write it like this : `value = arrayName[0]` and this will return a one dimension array `[data1,data2,data3]`, that's what I used to get rowData.

Now we need to get a 2 dimension array again to be able to write back the new data to a range in the spreadsheet.  Therefor we create a new array (`var newData=[]` or `var newData = new Array()` does exactly the same), and in the for loop we add the rowData array to this new array... the result will be an array of arrays, that is actually what we were looking for and we can write this directly to the sheet in one single `setValues` statement.

Comment: I think what he was trying to do was fill all rows below row one with the values in a row one.

Comment: Yes, ScampMichael is correct. I'm trying to replicate the first code example which fills the range in col A. I'm attempting to do the same for the multi-column range of C:H. I could accomplish this on a column by column basis, but that's just a workaround.

Comment: ...Or maybe it's not a workaround. Maybe it needs to be constructed that way(??)

Comment: Or possibly along the lines of "for (var x=1; x<=lastRow; x++) { ......." (I'm just vamping ideas now, but I'm going to give that a try and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this seems to do it...

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow()  
  var rngVal = ss.getRange("C1:H1").getValues()
  for (var x=1; x<=lastRow; x++) {
  ss.getRange("C"+x+":H"+x).setValues(rngVal);
```

Comment: Yes it does but you should avoid writing to the sheet in a loop... it can become quite slow in you have a lot of rows. The cede I suggested in my edit does it at array level and writes back in one step with setValues..

Comment: I most certainly want to gear my coding habits towards array level solutions, so thank you for providing that solution. I wonder if you could assist me in understanding a few of those lines: 'var rowData = rngVal[0]' and 'var newData = []' and the second half of the For routine, '{newData.push(rowData)}'. I can piece everything else together, so understanding these 3 lines would prove invaluable to me going forward. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi, I added a few words of explanation, hoping I was clear :)  If not, don't hesitate to ask again.

Comment: @Serge insas - I highly appreciate the explanations. Very helpful! And just to clarify it in my head, you're saying that using this: "[]" is the equivalent to using: "new array()" ?  So it would just be two ways of indicating the same thing?  Also, what does "push" mean? Is that a way of saying "write"? So in this context it would be like saying: write the new array using the value of rowData (??). I really want to understand that relationship, because it appears that "push" and "arrays" are joined at the hip.

Comment: Push is not really like write, see it rather like 'add at the end'  since there is also a command called unshift that you can use to 'add at beginning' .Arrays are not necessarily easy to understand at first but so useful to work with that it's well worth the effort :-) you can have a look at some internet resources on the subject...  and lastly, pls consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Ok great. Thanks. I'll definitely be immersing myself in the subject of arrays. And yes, I meant to accept your answer first thing this morning. Now done. Thanks again.

Comment: thanks, have a look [here for example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp)