# Google sheets Script to batch process Eval(A:A)

Tags: arrays, batch-file, google-apps-script, google-sheets, eval

This is my first post and I apologise if I lay it out incorrectly. I am very new to scripts but have worked in excel and google sheets for a long time. I would really appreciate your help with the following.

**Problem:**

I need to take a string from A2:A and place the solved value in B2:B

**For Example:**

Take a string from a concatenated formula A1 "2+3" and place the result in B1 "5" but for 2'000 rows

**Slow and Unstable Solution:**

Currently i have a custom function:

```
function simple(data) {
return  eval(data);  
}
```

I place the function in B1 "=simple(A1)"

This works but is very slow. This is made worse by the fact that I need to have a solution that allows the user to insert and delete rows. I have therefore used an edit onChange function to insert the formula on the entire range B2:B. This results in the entire 2000 results running again.

**Attempt at New Solutions**

I have tried using "=simple(A1:A)" , "=ArrayFormula(simple(A1:A))" and a variety of other ways but it just places the un-evaluated string in the answer column.

My next thought was to run a batch script as per Goolges best practice suggestion. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices . The best i was able to achieve was to end up with the un-evaluated string as the answer again.

I think the problem lies in converting from a range to a 1 dimensional array, evaluating each row and then turning it back into a range [Fill a range (multiple columns) down multiple rows - google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16071297/fill-a-range-multiple-columns-down-multiple-rows-google-apps-script) . I really don't know what I am doing and the best i came up with was the following:

```
function notSoSimple() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastRow = 6  
  var range = ss.getRange("C1:H1").getValues();// get an array of the first row
  var rowData = range[0]
  var newData = [rowData]
  for(n=1;n<lastRow;++n){
  var huh = [eval(rowData)]
  //newData.push(rowData)  
  }
  ss.getRange("C2:H2").setValues(huh);
  }
```

I realise it is not running vertically as in my initial requirement but I just want to get it working first. I don't know how to write the "for" statement to eval() an individual string in the array and then join it again.

I have tried to adapt a number of other scripts as well but no luck. Appreciate any help!

Comment: Update:

Example String (each line varies): 150*1*4.5/9/1*(0.6*0.6*1)

function simple(data) {
return  eval(data);  
}

results with answer = 27

function notSoSimple(){

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Main Data");
  var lastRow = 10

  for (var i = 1; i <= lastRow; i++){

    var lineFinal = sheet.getRange([i], 6);
    var lineValues = eval(lineFinal.getValues());
    
    var resultRange = sheet.getRange([i], 9);

    if (lineFinal != ''){ // 
      resultRange.setValue(lineValues);
      }
    }
}

results with: 150*1*4.5/9/1*(0.6*0.6*1)

Answer (score 0):

From [ahab](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/j_yVR3-i-bQ) for the example you give (ie *addition*):

```
=SUM(SPLIT(A1,"+"))
```

and copy down to suit.

Comment: Thanks Ahab. That was just a simple argument that i used. Users may enter much larger strings. For example:

(1+16/2)+6/4*3*(1+6)